# Promoting representation of a subgroup to representation of an action groupoid

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-actions, groupoids, hecke-algebras

Suppose I have a group $G$, a subgroup $K \leq G$, and a representation $(\sigma, V)$ of $K$.

There is a natural left action of $G$ on $X := G/K \times G/K$ given by $g \cdot (g'K,g''K) = (gg'K,gg''K)$. From this I can form the quotient groupoid, which I'll denote $[G \backslash X]$ (the objects are elements of $X$, and $\mathrm{Hom}_{[G \backslash X]}(x,x') = \{ g \in G : g \cdot x = x' \}$).

I define a *representation* of $[G \backslash X]$ to be a functor $[G \backslash X] \to \mathrm{Vect}_k$, where the target is the category of vector spaces on $k$.

My question is: is there a "natural" representation of $[G \backslash X]$ that one can define from $(\sigma, V)$? It seems like there could maybe be one, because the automorphism groups of the groupoid are exactly intersections of pairs of conjugates of $K$.

The problem seems to be that $\mathrm{Aut}_{[G \backslash X]}(gK,g'K) = gKg^{-1} \cap g'K(g')^{-1}$... and if this should act on the vector space $V$ then how should it act? $h \cdot v = \sigma(g^{-1}hg) \cdot v$? $h \cdot v = \sigma((g')^{-1}hg') \cdot v$?

This question is admittedly a bit vague, and I guess I'm more just wondering if anyone has seen any kind of construction like this before. In my context, I'm thinking about derived Hecke algebras.

Comment: I would choose the representations of these intersections that arise when you induce $\sigma$ up to G and restrict to K' via the Mackey decomposition

Comment: So for each $g$ you get an action of $gKg^{-1}$ on V by conjugating into K and acting.  Then restrict to the intersection.  This will give a functor on the groupoid in the obvious way.

Comment: To define this explicitly you probably need to choose double coset representatives but the resulting representation is unique up to equivalence.